# New gesture - Swipe left to right - as shortcut for Back button in UINavigationController in old app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, back-button

iOS 7 sports a new gesture, swiping left to right across the screen as a shortcut for the Back button in a UINavigationController.

My app does not seem to be picking up this behavior for free. What do I need to do to make this gesture available to my iOS app (built for iOS 5.1 and later in Xcode 4.6.3)?

Here's an article with video, [The new gesture in iOS 7 you want to know about](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57602633-285/the-new-gesture-in-ios-7-you-want-to-know-about/), from a user's perspective.

The answer may have something to do with [interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer) which is a [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/removeTarget%3aaction%3a) subclass.

Answer (score 4):

It should work automatically if the back button is visible. If you are displaying a leftBarButtonItem instead of the back button, the gesture will not be present by default. Also, if you are using a UINavigationBar but not a UINavigationController, you won't see this functionality.

If you are using a UINavigationController and your view controller's navigation item contains a leftBarButtonItem, it's still possible to add functionality for the swipe left to right gesture of the navigation controller, by attaching a delegate to the navigation controller's [interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer).

**EDIT:** I didn't notice that you're building against SDK 5.1. This is a new feature in the iOS 7 SDK, so I believe you'll need to build with Xcode 5 against the iOS 7 SDK in order to make use of the new feature.

Comment: I'm using a plain-vanilla `UINavigationController` with automatically generated `Back` buttons. I assumed that my app would get the Swipe-to-go-Back feature for free in iOS 7. But apparently not.

Comment: You are building against SDK 5.1. This feature is not there in 5.1.Take latest SDK to build and with default back button it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect solution for custom **leftBarButtom** problem

**Set the gesture delegate to the navigation controller**

you need to subclass UINavigationController and implement "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate" protocol in it, and add some code on viewDidLoad see the following code below

CustomNavigationController.m

> @interface CBNavigationController : UINavigationController
>    @end
>
> @implementation CBNavigationController
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {   __weak CBNavigationController *weakSelf = self;
>
>   if ([self
>     respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])   {
>     self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = weakSelf;   } }
>
> @end

and just inherit this class to your Navigation controller, it will work perfect.

Comment: You can just do `self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`. The delegate is declared in `UIGestureRecognizer` as weak. You also don't need to check `[self respondsToSelector:....]`, the compiler will give you the warning if it doesn't implement the protocol.