# Is the iPhone touch surface larger than the screen?

Tags: ios, iphone

[I have a weird iPhone bug, only tested on an iPhone 5S.]

My app has two panes, each of width 320px. When the right pane is fully visible (and the left pane fully hidden), I can sometimes tap a button on the *left* pane. This button touches the left pane's right border. It is hard to trigger the bug, the trigger surface seems to be on the edge of the phone.

If the iPhone 5S touch surface is no larger than the 320px screen, this should not be possible.

Is the iPhone 5S touch surface larger than the 320px screen? I.e., do the iPhone 5S screen edges have a few extra pixels of touch sensitivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with your interface, not the hardware. The touchable bounds region of the button may be bigger than the apparent visible drawing of the button. Thus, it may be invisibly sticking into your screen from the left. To confirm this, try making the invisible visible, by giving the button a background color that shows its actual dimensions.

Oh, one more thing. You may be positioning your panes off by one pixel. That would be enough to bring *one* pixel width of the button onto the screen - and thus would make it, with difficulty, tappable.

Since both panes will never be visible simultaneously, why not avert this entire issue by adding some space between the panes?

Answer (score 0):

You can check pane (button) location by printing it's frame into console. Now you know for sure, if button edge is on-screen or not:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
```

Btw I'm wondering, if this could be related to iOS7 feature "([New gesture - Swipe left to right - as shortcut for Back button in UINavigationController in old app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19325274/113079))"?

Comment: The button is an HTML button in a `WKWebView`. I've double checked that the margin and padding does not overflow.